# "hilarious AND terrifying"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to figure out if there is a word that means "both hilarious and terrifying." Thank you.

Comment: Yes, both hilarious and terrifying.

Answer (score 4):

Although informal and not official, **hilarifying** fits:

> #### Hilarifying
>
> - An absolutely horrifying situation that one still finds hilarious.

([Urban Dictionary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.urbandictionary.com/define.php%3Fterm%3DHilarifying%26amp%3Dtrue))

Comment: +1 because why not? And there are also hits for horrifilarious, but they are not up to the scholarly standards of the Urban Dictionary.

Comment: My immediate thought exactly… except I didn't realise someone else had made it up already.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly tongue-in-cheek solution would be to say "it's a scream!"

Colloquially this is a (mildly) dated way of saying it's hilarious, but the screaming part can also imply terror.

See for example [It's a scream! A horror-bly funny comedy](http://www.samuelfrench.com/p/5353/its-a-scream-a-horror-bly-funny-comedy)

Answer (score -1):

Officially, *Freakish* would have the correct definition you're looking for.

Freakish via [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/freakish)

> 1. Markedly unusual or abnormal; strange: freakish weather; a freakish combination of styles.
> 2. Relating to or being a freak: a freakish extra toe.
> 3. Capricious or whimsical.

I'm not sure you'll get much better without simply using both words, as they're not often related. *Ambivalent emotions* would describe the contradicting feeling.

Ambivalent Via [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ambivalent)

> 1. Having mixed feelings about someone or something; being unable to choose between two (usually opposing) courses of action: The whole
>      family was ambivalent about the move to the suburbs. She is regarded
>      as a morally ambivalent character in the play.
> 2. Psychology. of or relating to the coexistence within an individual of positive and negative feelings toward the same person, object, or
>      action, simultaneously drawing him or her in opposite directions.

Comment: Can you add more as to how freakish conveys terror and hilarity? I am genuinely curious about your take on that word.